# Position of 提供 in 这椅子是专为老年人提供的

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

```
这椅子是专为老年人提供的. This chair is provided for the old man.
```

I don't understand why 提供 is at the end of sentence. I thought 提供 could be placed before 专为.

Comment: What’s the source of your given sample sentence?

Comment: This is an answer in a HSK test

Comment: I would say "这把椅子是老年人**专用**的" or "这把椅子是**专门**提供给老年人**使用**的" instead. The original sentence feels unnatural to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is all because of that 为

Basically the following two sentences have the same meaning:

这椅子是专门提供给老人的

这椅子是专(门)**为**老人提供的

English translation will be:

We provided this chair specifically **for** the elders

It is actually quite common to use the 为 to move the verb after the subject to emphasize the **"for"**

For example,

My heart only **beats** **for** *you*

我的心只**为**你**跳动**

Comment: Is it okay for the sentence to omit using a classifier? i.e. 這個椅子 or 這把椅子

Comment: Above there are 2 sentences beginning 这椅子是. Your (romantic) example is: 我的心只为你跳动. What would be your sentence when 跳动 is not at the end of the sentence?

Comment: @MuchAppreciated25 这个 can omit using a specific classifier in most cases.

Comment: @Pedroski you can say 我的心跳只是为你 again this is not as "native" as the other one, that's why I would recommend to use the "为 + subject + verb form".

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. In these two sentences, 这椅子是专门提供给老人的 and 这椅子是专(门)为老人提供的, you omit a classifier. It's just 【这】 +【 椅子】。Is that okay? No need for a classifier in between?

Comment: @MuchAppreciated25 It is totally OK. As a native speaker, I don't use the classifier when I use 这 or 那